# convert month name to number in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

```
+--------+-----+---+----+----+----+----+-----+-----------+-----------+
|Currency|Month|Day|Year|Open|High| Low|Close|     Volume| Market Cap|
+--------+-----+---+----+----+----+----+-----+-----------+-----------+
|   tezos|  Dec| 04|2019|1.29|1.32|1.25| 1.25| 46,048,752|824,588,509|
|   tezos|  Dec| 03|2019|1.24|1.32|1.21| 1.29| 41,462,224|853,213,342|
|   tezos|  Dec| 02|2019|1.25|1.26|1.20| 1.24| 27,574,097|817,872,179|
|   tezos|  Dec| 01|2019|1.33|1.34|1.25| 1.25| 24,127,567|828,296,390|
|   tezos|  Nov| 30|2019|1.31|1.37|1.31| 1.33| 28,706,667|879,181,680|
|   tezos|  Nov| 29|2019|1.28|1.34|1.28| 1.31| 32,270,224|867,085,098|
|   tezos|  Nov| 28|2019|1.26|1.35|1.22| 1.28| 44,240,281|845,073,679|
|   tezos|  Nov| 27|2019|1.24|1.27|1.16| 1.26| 47,723,271|829,672,736|
|   tezos|  Nov| 15|2019|1.22|1.26|1.15| 1.17| 32,203,363|773,992,543|
+--------+-----+---+----+----+----+----+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

This is my pyspark datagram, how can I convert month name to number??? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use **`from_unixtime and unix_timestamp`** functions.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+-----+
#|Month|
#+-----+
#|  Dec|
#|  Nov|
#+-----+  

df.withColumn("mnth_name",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("Month"),'MMM'),'MM')).show()
#+-----+---------+
#|Month|mnth_name|
#+-----+---------+
#|  Dec|       12|
#|  Nov|       11|
#+-----+---------+
```